# Binary File Input/Output with Data*Stream Classes

Tags: java, file, io

I have the following test program that is writing out a `Person` record's field values using `java.io.DataOutputStream` and it writes them out just fine. Then, after a pause that I put in to check the data file, it is supposed to read in the same three records using `java.io.DataInputStream`, but it reads in the first record, the `Person.id` of the second record and throws the `EOFException`, but is not at the end of file. Here's the code:

```java
public class BinaryFileAccessTest {

    private static File dataFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "dataFile.dat");
    
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
        
        people.add(new Person("Dough", "John", new Date(70, 03, 17), 23500.00d));
        people.add(new Person("Smith", "Sean", new Date(70, 05, 06), 53900.00d));
        people.add(new Person("Carrick", "Rebecca", new Date(59, 06, 13), 20000.00d));
        
        System.out.println("From List<Person> people:");
        for (Person p : people) {
            System.out.println("\tCreated: " + p.toString());
        }
        
        try (DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dataFile))) {
            System.out.println("Writing Person to file:");
            for (Person p : people) {
                out.writeLong(p.getId());
                out.writeUTF(p.getLastName());
                out.writeUTF(p.getFirstName());
                out.write(p.getBirthDate().toString().getBytes());
                out.writeDouble(p.getSalary());
                
                System.out.println("\tWrote: " + p.toString());
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("An error occurred writing to " + dataFile);
            System.err.println(ex);
            ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
        
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean exit = false;
        while (!exit) {
            String input = keyboard.nextLine();
            if (input != null) {
                exit = true;
            }
        }
        
        try (DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(dataFile))) {
            people.clear();
            System.out.println("Reading Person from file:");
            
            while (true) {
                Person p = new Person();
                p.setId(in.readLong());
                p.setLastName(in.readUTF());
                p.setFirstName(in.readUTF());
                p.setBirthDate(new Date(in.read()));
                p.setSalary(in.readDouble());
                
                System.out.println("\tRead: " + p.toString());
                people.add(p);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
//            if (!(ex instanceof EOFException)) {
                System.err.println("An error occurred writing to " + dataFile);
                System.err.println(ex);
                ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
//            } else {
//                System.out.println("End of file reached.");
//            }
        }
        
        System.out.println("From List<Person> people:");
        for (Person p : people) {
            System.out.println("\tContains: " + p.toString());
        }
       
    }

}
```

The output from this program is:

```
From List<Person> people:
    Created: Dough, John [birth=Fri Apr 17 00:00:00 CST 1970; salary=23500.0
    Created: Smith, Sean [birth=Sat Jun 06 00:00:00 CDT 1970; salary=53900.0
    Created: Carrick, Rebecca [birth=Mon Jul 13 00:00:00 CDT 1959; salary=20000.0
Writing Person to file:
    Wrote: Dough, John [birth=Fri Apr 17 00:00:00 CST 1970; salary=23500.0
    Wrote: Smith, Sean [birth=Sat Jun 06 00:00:00 CDT 1970; salary=53900.0
    Wrote: Carrick, Rebecca [birth=Mon Jul 13 00:00:00 CDT 1959; salary=20000.0

Reading Person from file:
    Read: Dough, John [birth=Wed Dec 31 18:00:00 CST 1969; salary=1.3403241663660614E243
```

In the second `try...catch` block, the first record (for John Dough) is read in and stored in the `people` list just fine. On the second iteration of the `while` loop, it reads in the ID value for Sean Smith, then when reading in the last name, it throws the `EOFException`, even though it is not at the end of the file. When I look at the contents of the file during the program execution pause, it has three blocks of data, which are clearly visible:

```
ꑢ?ꣁ???甔? 珐????? ꗌ?쵐?
```

Of course, it looks different in the editor in which I look at it, but there are three clear blocks of data present. Yet, after reading the one field from the second block of data, it somehow hits the EOF.

Can anyone explain why this would be? It seems that if these classes are working correctly, when data is written out as I did, then read in by the inverse class, it would read in exactly as it was written out, so it should read in the same number of datapoints as were written.

I guess the better question is, where did I screw this up? ;)

Thank you for any help you can provide!

-SC

[EDIT]
I also just noticed that John Dough's salary is not being read back in as the same value as written, neither is his `birthDate`. Why would this be?

Thx!

[EDIT-2]
Here's the `Person` Java Bean:

```java
public class Person {
    
    private long id;
    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;
    private Date birthDate;
    private double salary;
    
    public Person() {
        
    }
    
    public Person (String lastName, String firstName, Date birthDate, double salary) {
        this.id = System.currentTimeMillis();
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public Date getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }

    public void setBirthDate(Date birthDate) {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getLastName() + ", " + getFirstName() + " [birth=" + getBirthDate() + "; salary=" + getSalary();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add your `Person` class to the question to make it a [mre] and we can be sure that the problem is not within there.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. And even if you insist on using `Date`, stay far away from its 3-arg constructor. It’s been deprecated for 25 years because it works unreliably across time zones. For a birthdate use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Why are you not using `ObjectOutputStream`? It would make things a lot easier

Comment: @cyberbrain: The `Person` class is just a standard Java Bean, but I'll edit and include it as well.

Comment: @OleV.V.: I typically don't use the `Date` class for the reasons you mentioned, but just went with it in this test as something simple that was neither specifically numeric, nor textual.

Comment: @g00se: I had been serializing the data lists to file and deserializing them back into list objects, but when I got to a complicated record (approximately 40 fields), it was not working for some reason, so I thought that I would give the `Data*Stream`s a try...The frustrations are seeming to not be worth the effort.

Comment: It's dead easy with your use case - you simply serialize your collection called `people` One write, one read

Comment: @g00se: As I had said, the serialization was working until it wasn't. See my comment to cyberbrain's answer...

Answer (score 3):

As per [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read()#read(byte%5B%5D)), the `read()` method:

> Reads a byte of data from this input stream. This method blocks if no input is yet available.

So you are not reading the birth date string, but the first char in your birth date string.

I suggest writing your birthdate string using `writeUTF()` like you did with other strings and read it back using `readUTF()`. Otherwise you will need to explicitly state the number of characters (bytes) in the birthdate string to be able to recover it with `read(byte[] b, int off, int len)`.

Comment: You are right, the `read()` method of `FileInputStream` just read one byte. I edited my answer. My second point of requiring the string length to recover it via `read(byte[] b, int off, int len)` remains valid, though.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that you use a byte array to write out the date, while you read back an `int` that is than (implicitly) casted to a `long` to recreate that `Date` object.

You can e.g. use

```
out.writeLong(p.getBirthDate().getTime());
```

to write your birthdate and

```
p.setBirthDate(new Date(in.readLong()));
```

to read it back.

But I actually would recommend that you use `java.io.ObjectOutputStream` to write and `java.io.ObjectInputStream` to read back your data.
To use them, you will have to either add `implements java.io.Serializable` to your `Person` class (and nothing more), or you implement the interface `java.io.Externalizable` with its methods `readExternal` and `writeExternal` and maybe don't use binary representation for the contents of that file, but a String representation like XML, JSON, YAML or anything like that.

Then you can use the `writeObject` and `readObject` methods of the according streams once per object to write or read.

Please note that the code you are using for the test will always throw an `EOFException` once it has read back the objects you wrote because you read back in an endless loop and do neither stop after 3 records nor have written the number of objects first so you could read that back to stop. You even could define an artificial `Person` object as end marker after which you stop reading.

(With `Object*Stream`s you could write out the whole `ArrayList` and also read it back in without any looping in your own code.)

Comment: I was using `Object*Stream`s until they didn't work with a Java Bean that had around 40 fields in it. For some reason, when I'd serialize my `ArrayList`, it would seem to work fine (as in, no exceptions thrown). But, when I'd read the object back in using `ObjectInputStream`, the `ArrayList` would only have either the first record, or the last record, in it, for some reason depending upon whether there were an odd or even number of records stored in the `ArrayList`. after 10 records, only the last one would get deserialized from file...

Comment: Also, I'm trying to avoid storing in plain text (CSV, XML, JSON, etc). I know how I am about opening random files in editors to see what their made of and I want to keep the data protected from any type of modification from outside of my program...;)

Comment: Good luck with the protection part ;) If you want just to prevent accidental modifications I would recommend that you add some kind of checksum or digest to your file. To prevent intentional modification, you will have a hard time without some kind of protected environment where you can store that checksum for comparison. But that wasn't your question, sorry.

Comment: oh, and I just tested with `Object*Stream` to write and read the `ArrayList` and didn't have any problems, so I would encourage you to add another SO question with that problem.

Comment: Thanks for the luck! I just want to keep my users' data as secure as possible. To that end, the application I am creating only connects to the network to check for updates, and that's it. Personally, I have always been curious about what's in a file, so I have no problem attempting to open the file in a text editor, or just dumping its contents on the command line. Being that way myself, I am just trying to protect my data from people...well...like ME! :-P

Comment: Yeah, normally I don't have any problems with `Object*Stream`s either. I think it's just something about my rather large Java Bean class...Leave it to me to have stuff screw up in weird ways...I'm Irish, so my luck is always in and spelled B-A-D...Maybe I should quit programming and become  a beta tester ;)

Comment: I'll second that suggestion to post a question about the faled seidliazation